# pass typesafe config file in maven

Tags: scala, maven, typesafe-config

How can I pass a config file to a scala program in `maven (3.0.5)`?

The following does not seem to work. Using `scala-maven-plugin (3.1.6)`.

```
mvn clean compile scala:run -DmainClass=org.mitchus.myprog.MyMain -Dconfig.file=my.conf
[...]
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException                                    
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)             
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)                        
    at scala_maven_executions.MainHelper.runMain(MainHelper.java:164)          
    at scala_maven_executions.MainWithArgsInFile.main(MainWithArgsInFile.java:26)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError                               
    at org.mitchus.myprog.MyMain.main(MyMain.scala)                            
    ... 6 more                                                                 
Caused by: com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing: No configuration setting found for key 'mykey'
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.findKey(SimpleConfig.java:124)    
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.find(SimpleConfig.java:145)       
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.find(SimpleConfig.java:151)       
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.find(SimpleConfig.java:159)       
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.find(SimpleConfig.java:164)       
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.getObject(SimpleConfig.java:218)  
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.getConfig(SimpleConfig.java:224)  
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.getConfig(SimpleConfig.java:33)   
    at com.github.kxbmap.configs.ConfigsInstances$$anonfun$configsAtPath$1.apply(Configs.scala:74)
    at com.github.kxbmap.configs.ConfigsInstances$$anonfun$configsAtPath$1.apply(Configs.scala:74)
    at com.github.kxbmap.configs.Configs$$anonfun$atPath$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Configs.scala:43)
    at com.github.kxbmap.configs.Configs$$anonfun$atPath$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Configs.scala:43)
    at com.github.kxbmap.configs.package$EnrichTypesafeConfig$.get$extension(package.scala:36)
    at org.mitchus.myprog.ConfigLoading$class.$init$(ConfigLoading.scala:24)   
    at org.mitchus.myprog.MyMain$.<init>(MyMain.scala:16)                      
    at org.mitchus.myprog.MyMain$.<clinit>(MyMain.scala)                       
    ... 7 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `-Dconfig.file` to the `jvmArgs` property of the plugin.

Comment: It works if I put in the pom.xml. However I would like to be able to specify it from the command line, if possible.